# Complex function composition in 1 line | Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming, function-composition

function composition of single argument functions is a simple 1 liner.

how would I (if it's possible) write the following composition in 1 line?

```
    def fn(x: int) -> str:
        def inner(a, b):
            return strjoin(a, g(b))
        return inner(*f(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert any one-line function whose only statement is a `return` to a `lambda` trivially. So you *can* write it this way.

```
def fn(x: int) -> str:
  return (lambda a, b: strjoin(a, g(b)))(*f(x))
```

Now, as for *why* you would do that, I'm not sure, unless you're getting paid by the line of code and abhor the idea of making money.

Most people would write the more approachable

```
def fn(x: int) -> str:
  a, b = f(x)
  return strjoin(a, g(b))
```